# Glassfish 4.1 LogFactory and WSSElementFactory NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, apache-commons

When I run my rest api point on a Glassfish 4.1 server I face following `NoClassDefFoundError` even if I ship the ear with `commons-logging` as dependecy respectively even if the library is unpacked under `WEB-INF\lib`

Also it look like that I don't face the problem using Glassfish 4.0

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

First `LogFactory` isn't found

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:252)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:463)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:191)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161)
```

and then `WSSElementFactory` isn't too

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.util.WSSElementFactory
at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:252)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:463)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:191)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Maybe* my answer is *little* outdated, but I've encountered the same problem with Glassfish 4.1.1 and managed to solve it by updating Metro libraries

Here is an instruction:

1. Download and unzip https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases//org/glassfish/metro/metro-standalone/2.3.1/metro-standalone-2.3.1.zip
2. Delete (backup) some files from your **glassfish/modules** folder:

- jaxb-extra-osgi.jar
- jaxb-osgi.jar
- stax2-api.jar
- webservices-extra-jdk-packages.jar
- webservices-osgi.jar
- woodstox-core-asl.jar

3. Replace them with **metro/osgi** content from unpacked zip
4. Stop Glassfish
5. Delete content of **domain1/generated** and **domain1/osgi-cache** folders
6. Start Glassfish

It worked for me, both errors were gone

Hope it'll help someone

Comment: Pretty cool  I don't work on that project anymore, so can't tell if it would help or not, but super happy that you shared a solution.  Thank you!